# Why does b2 build with gcc4.6 when 4.8 is default?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, c++11

While building a custom Boost.Python project, I encountered build errors that originated in lacking c++11 support of `gcc-4.6` (the code to wrap compiled fine under VS2012). So I upgraded to 4.8 and used `$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50` to redirect executions of gcc to the newer version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
```

So far, so good. But  as the error messages didn't change and on further inspection I noticed something:

```
link.jam: No such file or directory
...patience...
...patience...
...found 1710 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ bin/gcc-4.6/debug/extending.o  //WHAT?
```

It looks like b2 still uses `gcc-4.6`. Yes it is still installed, but didn't I just replace it with `gcc-4.8`? I am very confused...

Also, can I specify the tollset-version manually? I tried `toolset=gcc4.8` but that just ends in an error that `gcc4.8.jam` doesn't exist...

Comment: Did you update-alternatives g++ too ?

Comment: oh shit. Looks like that might have been the problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I forgot to

> $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50

That was kind of dumb, but this will hopefully help someone in the future. All kudos to @nos!